# Is there a way to avoid producing nested lists when allocating lists?

Tags: python, list, algorithm, arraylist, output

[Here's a git link if you want to see the full code/run the program for yourself.](https://github.com/r0me777/RITMO.git)

The summary of my problem is: I have a nested list, and lists inside that list should move to another list which they do. Those lists that are moved end up being triple nested for some reason like this: [[[66, 81]], [[83, 41]]] instead of this:            [ ... [83,41], [66,81] ]

That I made a program that follows a predictive algorithm RITMO. The program has Nodes/Drones that complete tasks: (moving to points).

This randomly generates a list of (x,y) values. It's messy but it still works. (pointgen)

```
randomList = []
    randomList1 = []
    pointlist = []
    for i in range(1000):  #This is overkill and could be accomplished with neater code but it works.
       r=random.randint(1,100)
       r1=random.randint(1,100)
       if r not in randomList:
          randomList.append(r)
       if r1 not in randomList1:
           randomList1.append(r1)
    while len(randomList1) > numofp:
        randomList1.pop()
    while len(randomList) > numofp:
        randomList.pop()

    for i in range(0, len(randomList)):
        insidelist = []
        insidelist.append(randomList[i]) #X
        insidelist.append(randomList1[i]) #Y
        pointlist.append(insidelist) #creats massive point list.

    return pointlist
```

This takes a the list from above and randomly breaks it into (min_length & max_length) 3-7 segments. (pointilist)

```
result = []

while input_list:
    sublist_length = random.randint(min_length, max_length) #Gen random num
    if sublist_length > len(input_list):
        sublist_length = len(input_list)

    selected_elements = input_list[:sublist_length]
    result.append(selected_elements) #Splice section
    input_list = input_list[sublist_length:]

return result
```

```
    newPointlist = break_list_into_sublists(oldPointlist, 3, 7)

    for i in range(0, AmountofNodes): #List of 5 Nodes/Drones randomly given name & points
        Nodelist.append(Node(name_gen(), newPointlist[i - 1], 5)) # 5 is queue/task max
```

Output: You can see how lists in tasks are moved to the positions list

1. Name: sJ\Q# Current tasks: 2 lists of tasks: [[[66, 81]], [[83, 41]]] queue size threshold: 5 positions: [[77, 49], [48, 59], [71, 35], [67, 85]]

Task moves from list of task to list of positions

2. Name:sJ\Q# Current tasks: 1 list of tasks: [[[66, 81]]] queue size threshold: 5 positions: [[77, 49], [48, 59], [71, 35], [67, 85], [[83, 41]]]

The problem is I have no idea where "[[[66, 81]], [[83, 41]]]"
triple nested lists or elements are coming from. They should just be  [ ... [83,41], [66,81] ]

It might be an error in how the Node object moves tasks from different nodes that results in unnecessary nesting [Here's the link to Git there are only 3 files:  main, droneobject , randomnodenamgen](https://github.com/r0me777/RITMO.git)

If anyone could help me out that would be great!!

Comment: It looks to me like triple nesting is exactly how the output *should* be structured. You want a list (layer 1) of segments (layer 2) of pairs (layer 3) of ints.

Comment: If you want help, then you need to post a **short** but **complete** program that demonstrates your problem.  Instead, you have posted **incomplete** code with large parts missing, and sample output that came from ... some other part of the code, apparently?  Because it sure didn't come from **this** code.

Comment: @JohnGordon It's too big to show on stack, you should just download the code to see for yourself.

Comment: @user2357112 Hmm I think your right, I first generated a list [ [], [], [], []...] and broke it up [ [], [], [] ] , [ [], [], [], [], [] ] , [ [], [] ], .. ] and then put those list into nodes. I just don't understand how some have more brackets than others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like your second excerpt is causing the nesting:

```
selected_elements = input_list[:sublist_length]
result.append(selected_elements) #Splice section
input_list = input_list[sublist_length:]
```

`input_list` is a list of 2-element lists. So is `selected_elements`. `result` starts as an empty list and has lists of lists appended to it, making it 3 lists deep.
If you rewrite it...

```
selected_elements = input_list[:sublist_length]
result = result + selected_elements #Splice section
input_list = input_list[sublist_length:]
```

... it should only be 2 lists deep.